# Cannot change totalFileSizeName and uuidName

Tags: fine-uploader

When I set the request parameters names, such as

```
$j("#thumbnail-fine-uploader").fineUploader({
    request: {
        totalFileSizeName: 'myFileSize',
        uuidName: 'myUuid',
        endpoint: 'http://myWebSite.com/',
        inputName: 'myFile'
    }
});
```

And I upload a file, the POST is this

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryvm7FCEHa9CiKn0mw
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qquuid"

0dd9cf34-79d4-4451-854d-f0746b83a2d2
------WebKitFormBoundaryvm7FCEHa9CiKn0mw
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qqfilename"

1.txt
------WebKitFormBoundaryvm7FCEHa9CiKn0mw
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qqtotalfilesize"

11
------WebKitFormBoundaryvm7FCEHa9CiKn0mw
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myFile"; filename="1.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Note that the file name was correctly changed to "myFile", and the endpoint is also correct (not shown here), but totalFileSizeName and uuidName remain as their default value: "qqtotalfilesize" and "qquuid".

Is this a bug?  Or am I using it incorrectly?

Using jquery.fineuploader-4.1.0.js and latest version of Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definitely appears to be a bug. After peering at the code, it looks like any custom UUID and total file size parameter names were lost on the long journey from options to upload request.

This likely occurred during one of the large refactoring efforts that took place over the last couple releases.  We are [currently developing a more comprehensive set of unit tests](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1063) to make it less likely to introduce regressions in these these types of lesser-used options/workflows.

In the meantime, you'll need to make good with the default values for these options.  If there is anything keeping you from using the default values at this time, please comment on [the case I just opened](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1065) so we can make it more of a priority to push out a hotfix release.

Comment: Thanks so much for the timely response! I love your use of stackoverflow as the main support forum, the excellent documentation/demos on the website, and github for open source development and bug tracking. I'm still evaluating the tool right now but probably will purchase a commercial license to support the great work you do!

Comment: Thanks for the nice comments @DWu.  Is this bug something you need fixed as soon as possible, or can it wait until the next release?

Comment: It can definitely wait (it's minor and I can work around it...I don't really "need" to change it from the default value). Thanks!

Comment: Note that this has been fixed in the develop branch, so it will be part of the next planned release, at the latest.

Comment: Just bought a commercial license.  Before I discovered Fine-uploader, I was trying to implement my own uploader, and of course, I quickly ran into significant legacy browser (ahem, IE) issues.  It took only a few days to integrate fine-uploader to our site thanks to the excellent documentations, and now our website's uploader works and looks a lot better :)  Thanks for the library!